# GCC linking a static library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I have seen questions like these on SO but everyone has different answers and directory structures that aren't working for me.

My makefile:

```
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g -std=c++11
TARGET = main
OBJECT_FILES = BingResultSet.o main.o
INC_PATH = -I HTTPClientLib/include
LIB_PATH = -L HTTPClientLib/lib/

start: clean BingResultSet.o main.o
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) $(INC_PATH) $(LIB_PATH) $(OBJECT_FILES) -o $(TARGET)
    rm -f *.o

BingResultSet.o: BingResultSet.cpp BingResultSet.h
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) $(INC_PATH) $(LIB_PATH) -c BingResultSet.cpp

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) $(INC_PATH) $(LIB_PATH) -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECT_FILES) $(TARGET)
```

My file structure:

```
/Desktop/DataMiner/.cpp, .h, and makefile
/Desktop/DataMiner/HTTPClientLib/include/HTTPClient.h
/Desktop/DataMiner/HTTPClientLib/lib/HTTPClient.a
```

What's the correct way to link my static lib in my makefile?

Comment: A makefile should not require running `clean` before building again to get reasonable results. If you need that your makefile is not properly written. Every target should create a file of the target name (not some other name) so that make can do its job correctly.

Comment: Are you asking how to link `HTTPClient.a` into your output `main` binary? Do you know how linking with a static library works normally? (That is how you would do this by hand without a makefile?)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "by hand without a makefile". I know how to link static libs on VS, but now im trying to build the project on Linux so the linking on gcc is a bit different and giving me some issues.

Comment: I mean do you know how you would do it at all? What command you would need to use to do it, etc.? (It sounds like no but I'm not clear whether the question is how to do that or how to get the makefile to do it correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my $0.02:

1. there was no static library involved. Assuming you meant the .o files
2. you mix dependencies and build rules, instead, avoid repeating build rules:

   ```
   $(TARGET): $(OBJECT_FILES)
       $(CXX) $(DEBUG) $(INC_PATH) $^ -o $@ $(LIB_PATH)

   %.o: %.cpp
       $(CXX) $(DEBUG) $(INC_PATH) -c $< -o $@
   ```
3. You used `CC` for a C++ compiler. That's strange. Use `CXX`
4. You used `LDFLAGS` when you were just compiling
5. You hardcoded the source and destination paths. Instead use [the automatic variables (`$^`, `$<` for source; `$@` for destination)](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)
6. You tried to hardcode header dependencies. That's error-prone and messes up source specification (you don't want `$^` to list `.h` files in your command line...). Instead, use `gcc -MM`¹ to generate the dependencies for you!

   Next, do a conditional include of those dependencies:

   ```
   .depends:
       $(CXX) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) -c *.cpp > $@

   -include .depends
   ```
7. It's usually handy to keep the .o files so you can speed up builds. Of course, this was not a good plan until you generated the header dependencies automatically. If you insist, you can comment the `.PRECIOUS` target. Intermediate targets are automatically deleted by GNU Make

Here's the integrated offering I ended up with:

```
CXX = g++
TARGET = main
OBJECT_FILES = BingResultSet.o main.o
INC_PATH = -I HTTPClientLib/include
LIB_PATH = -L HTTPClientLib/lib/

CPPFLAGS = -g -std=c++11
CPPFLAGS+= $(INC_PATH)

# standard derived flags:
CXXFLAGS+=$(CPPFLAGS)
LDFLAGS+=$(LIB_PATH)

start: .depends $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f .depends $(OBJECT_FILES) $(TARGET)

# to keep the .o files:
.PRECIOUS: $(OBJECT_FILES)

.depends:
    $(CXX) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) -c *.cpp > $@

-include .depends
```

On a very simple sample set of files you get:

```
$ make clean
rm -f .depends BingResultSet.o main.o main
$ make 
g++ -MM -g -std=c++11 -I HTTPClientLib/include -c *.cpp > .depends
g++  -I HTTPClientLib/include -c BingResultSet.cpp -o BingResultSet.o
g++  -I HTTPClientLib/include -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++  -I HTTPClientLib/include BingResultSet.o main.o -o main -L HTTPClientLib/lib/
$ cat .depends 
BingResultSet.o: BingResultSet.cpp BingResultSet.h
main.o: main.cpp BingResultSet.h
test.o: test.cpp
```

---

¹  (or similar, see man-page)

Comment: @shawna You can see the stream vid [around 29:00](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/modular-boost-refactor-makefile-and-more/) (excuse any expletives) ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))